# How to identify if a dependency is run time or build dependency?

Tags: ros, build, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating a package to subscribe to a topic from a node in another package. I understand that the only dependency required is the `message package`.  Is this a run time or build dependency?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239457/how-to-identify-if-a-dependency-is-run-time-or-build-dependency?/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using the messages when you build your code? If yes, they're a build dependency.

Are you using the messages when you run your code? If yes, they're a run-time dependency.

It is perfectly fine to have a package as both a build and run-time dependency.

This question and answer has a more in-depth discussion: http://answers.ros.org/question/238900/should-cc-packages-run_depend-on-_msgs-packages/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-07-13**:
Also worth mentioning [REP 140 "Package Manifest Format Two Specification"](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html). Has some nice explanations and of course introduces new tags.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-14**:
Thank You, both of you.